# How to print out Model Summary in Plotly Dash?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, plotly-dash, arima

Say I build an ARIMA model and I would like to display the model summary on dash exactly as in python, how can I do so?
The following is an example code. (I am using colab therefore `app = JupyterDash()` )

```
import yfinance as yf
import dash
import dash_html_components as HTML
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

app = JupyterDash() 

data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2017-01-01", end="2021-12-31")

arima = ARIMA(data["Close"], order=(1, 1, 1)).fit(disp=0)

arima.summary()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P(arima.summary()) #what should I type here?
])

app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=50800)
```

With the help of Daniel Al Mouiee, the following code get closer to the output in python.

```
summary = arima.summary()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P(str(summary), style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap'})
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the summary to a string and placing that in the div:

```py
summary = arima.summary()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.P(str(summary))
])
```

Comment: Thanks, it shows the text but everything sticks together. I use the following code `html.P(str(summary), style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap'})` but it is still not exactly the output in python.

Comment: What are you after exactly? If you want a table view you can try and capture that summary in a dataframe then visualize it in a dash datatable or dcc table for example

Comment: good idea thanks